# How can i calculate which part of a segment my ball will hit first?

Tags: java, vector, collision-detection

I have a surface with many segments with different inclination.

For every segment there are 4 known parameters:

startX 
startY
(x and y of the starting point of the segment)
stopX 
stopY
(x and y of the ending point of the segment)

Then i have a ball with center x and y and a direction vector dx and dy.

I'm able to know if my ball collides with the segment, and to calculate the new vector for the bounce INSIDE the segment.

What i'm missing is:

How can i detect if the ball hits the edge of the segment or inside and how to calculate the right bounce.

Comment: that's basic geometry: given two lines, calculate their intersection point: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html. If they intersect, just calculate the angle of intersection (e.g. the angle between the two lines).

Comment: Hi, i'm not a geometry expert, but the link you sent me is not giving the solution on how can i recognise if the ball hits first the corner or the inside of the segment, and how the bounce needs to be accordingly

Comment: stop looking for "the solution". You need to learn the concepts, and that link is the BEGINNING of the concept - how to caculate where two lines intersect. If you only look for solutions, you're in the wrong business. Learn how to use basic tools and you can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate like

i am assuming your ball having a radius which is in variable *radius*

```
boolean isHitRight = (startX + dx + radius ) >= stopX;

boolean isHitBottom = (startY + dy + radius ) >= stopY;


if(isHitRight) {
   // bounce ball left ..
} else if (isHitBottom) {
   // bounce ball up ...
}
```